# Error al agregar controlador ASP.NET MVC con Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

He creado un proyecto MVC con Entity Framework con Visual Studio 2019.

Siempre había podido agregar controladores ligados a los modelos que ya estan agregados correctamente. Sin embargo tenia mucho tiempo de no agregar un nuevo controlador y al querer agregar uno me sale el siguiente error
"Error al ejecutar el generador de códigos seleccionado:
No se pueden recuperar metadatos para 'Models.AUTOXDISTRITO'. Could not find the CLR type
for 'PC HH AndroidModel.TESTIGOXBOLETA'"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que estoy intentando agregar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puede estar pasando...?